# Нужны наводки по корректировке работы функции в коде

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Условие самой задачи:
в main ввести массив целых чисел (количество - с клавиатуры), в функции вернуть количество и сумму членов массива, которые не превышают среднее арифметическое членов массива.

Проблема в том, что функция ничего не возвращает - ни суммы нужных элементов, ни их количества. Подскажите, что не так в функции, заранее спасибо (код ниже).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int func(int* m, int &n)
{
    int i = 0, sr_znach, sum=0, k=0;
    for (i; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += *(m + i);
    }
    sr_znach = sum / n;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (*(m + i) <= sr_znach)
        {
            sum += *(m + i);
            k++;
        }
    }
    return k;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int* ms, n=0, i = 0;
    ms = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    if (!ms)
    {
        printf("Недостаточно памяти");
        return 0;
    }
        printf("Введите размерность массива: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("Введите массив: ");
    for (i; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", (ms + i));
    }
    func(ms, n);
}
```

Comment: Какой-то странный у вас "С со ссылками" - `int func(int* m, int &n)`... Странный возврат (два `return`). Целочисленное деление `sr_znach = sum / n;`

Comment: попробуйте вывести что-нибудь с `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы выделяете память перед тем, как попросили пользователя ввести размерность массива.

   То есть у вас `n = 0` вы выделяете память, а потом уже просите ввести размерность массива => ошибка выход за пределы массива

   Нужно сначала спросить у пользователя размерность, а потом уже выделять память.

   ```
   printf("Введите размерность массива: ");
   scanf_s("%d", &n);
   ms = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
   ```
2. Вы пишите в конце функции `func()` два `return`, но это так не работает, после первого же `return` у вас произойдет выход из функции. Чтобы передать из функции например кол-во слагаемых, нужно воспользоваться ссылками.

   Передача параметра по ссылке происходит следующим образом:

   ```
   int func(int* m, int n, int* new_n)
   ```

   Теперь функцию будет возвращать сумму по значению (через `return`), а кол-во слагаемых по ссылке (через `new_n`).

   Вот пример функции (где `...` это места кода, где ничего не менялось)

   ```
   int func(int* m, int n, int* new_n)
   {
       ...
       *new_n = k;
       return sum;
   }
   ```

И теперь вывод может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
int new_n = 0;
printf("Сумма: %d\n",func(ms, n, &new_n));
printf("Кол-во слагаемых: %d\n", new_n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас и правда C, попробуйте возврат через указатель:

```
void func(int* m, int n, int * count, int * Summa)
{
    int sum = 0, k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += *(m + i);
    }
    double sr_znach = (double)sum/n;
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (*(m + i) <= sr_znach)
        {
            sum += *(m + i);
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (count) *count = k;
    if (Summa) *Summa = sum;
}
```

Ну, а использовать ее -

```
printf("Введите массив: ");
for (i; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf_s("%d", (ms + i));
}
int count, sum;
func(ms, n, &count, &sum);
printf("Количество = %d, сумма = %d\n",count, sum);
```